# Check collinearity in 3d space, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, three.js

The problem is to detect whether 2 lines lays on the same straight line.
for example:

```
line1Start [0,0,0]
line1End [10, 0, 0]
line2Start [12, 0, 0]
line2End [15, 0, 0]
```

I need a method to check whether these 2 lines lays on the same level.

I have checked the direction with threejs methods. But it did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const areLinesCollinear = (a, b, p) => {
  const slopeXY = (coor1, coor2) => (coor2[1] - coor1[1]) / (coor2[0] - coor1[0]);
  const slopeXZ = (coor1, coor2) => (coor2[2] - coor1[2]) / (coor2[0] - coor1[0]);
  const slope1XY = slopeXY(a, b);
  const slope1XZ = slopeXZ(a, b);
  const slope2XY = slopeXY(b, p);
  const slope2XZ = slopeXZ(b, p);
  const slope3XY = slopeXY(p, a);
  const slope3XZ = slopeXZ(p, a);
  return (slope1XY === slope2XY &&
    slope2XY === slope3XY &&
    slope1XZ === slope2XZ &&
    slope2XZ === slope3XZ);
};
areLinesCollinear([0, 8, 7], [10, 8, 7], [12, 8, 7]); // true
areLinesCollinear([0, 8, 1], [10, 8, 1], [12, 8, 7]); // false
```